# How to create a button in following style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create two button which will float next to each other and also when we click one of them it will change background-color to #474e5d  and some shadow effect. I am very new to design please help me to do this.

[Click here to see the button design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWjXt.png)

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

```js
//js
const span2 = document.getElementById("span2")
const span1 = document.getElementById("span1")
span2.addEventListener("click",function  ( ) {
    const span3 = document.getElementById("span3")
    span3.style.left="150px"
    span3.innerHTML="Search by dictric"
    span3.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
})
span1.addEventListener("click",function  () {
    const span3 = document.getElementById("span3")
    span3.style.left="0px"
    span3.innerHTML="Search by pin code"
    span3.style.transition = "all 0.5s"; 
})
```

```css
  /* css */ 
        .sld_btn{
             display: flex; 
             width: 300px;
             height: 40px;
             border-radius: 25px;
             position: relative;
             background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102); 
            } 
            .sld_btn span{ 
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: all 0.5; 
        }
        #span3{ 
            border-radius: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width:150px ;
            background-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.5);  
        }
```

```html
  <!-- HTML -->
     <div class="sld_btn"> 
         <span class="span1" id="span1">Search by pin code</span>
         <span  id="span2">Search by dictric</span>
         <span class="span3" id="span3">Search by pin code</span>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close to what you are looking for. I can explain individual parts if you want.

Click on `Run Code Snippet` to see it working.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

function onButtonClick(event) {
  for (button of buttons) button.classList.remove('clickedButton');
  event.target.classList.add('clickedButton');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 32px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: max-content;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 32px;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.clickedButton {
  background-color: #474e5d;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #444;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button" onclick="onButtonClick(event)">Search by Pin Code</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="onButtonClick(event)">Search by District</div>
</div>
```